# Xamarin Forms Rowspan in CollectionView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem.
I created this CollectionView with a few dummy trades, that looks like this right now:
[image]

Now this is almost like I want it, except for 1 thing: I want the last column to get a rowspan over both the rows, like this:
[image]

Now if this was a regular Grid, I could do it with `Grid.RowSpawn`, but it is in a `CollectionView`, because I can have a lot of trades. The downside of the CollectionView is that each row is a different Grid, so they are actually not connected! Here is my code right now:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding agentOrderList}" Margin="0" HeightRequest="450">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="White"/>
                    <Grid RowSpacing="0" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="21" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="21" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="4" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="95" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="82" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Date}" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#00D8FF" FontSize="18" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Action}" TextColor="White" FontSize="18" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Coin}" TextColor="White" FontSize="18" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Price}" TextColor="White" FontSize="18" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding ProfitUSDT}" TextColor="{Binding ProfitColor}" FontSize="18" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding ProfitPerc}" TextColor="{Binding ProfitColor}" FontSize="18" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>

                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Now what is the best way to achieve this? Do I need to make a different view?
Please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have data cross over between cells in a `ListView`, so I think you will need to make each list item have a two row grid, so then you can have the last column span two rows.

However, I am confused. Your XAML code does not seem to match the screen shot of one cell. Your XAML code only seems to assign 5 columns, but I see 6 in your screen shots?

IN any case, you are correct, you will need to use one grid to display the Buy and Sell data so that that last column can span 2 rows.

UPDATE: Based on comments below, it seems a DataTemplateSelector may be required here. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

Partial extract from above link:

> A data template selector enables scenarios such as a ListView binding
>   to a collection of objects, where the appearance of each object in the
>   ListView can be chosen at runtime by the data template selector
>   returning a particular DataTemplate.
>
> Creating a DataTemplateSelector A data template selector is
>   implemented by creating a class that inherits from
>   DataTemplateSelector. The OnSelectTemplate method is then overridden
>   to return a particular DataTemplate, as shown in the following code
>   example:

```
public class PersonDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{ 
    public DataTemplate ValidTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate InvalidTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate (object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        return ((Person)item).DateOfBirth.Year >= 1980 ? ValidTemplate : InvalidTemplate;   
     } 
 }
```

> The OnSelectTemplate method returns the
>   appropriate template based on the value of the DateOfBirth property.
>   The template to return is the value of the ValidTemplate property or
>   the InvalidTemplate property, which are set when consuming the
>   PersonDataTemplateSelector.
>
> An instance of the data template selector class can then be assigned
>   to Xamarin.Forms control properties such as ListView.ItemTemplate. For
>   a list of valid properties, see Creating a DataTemplate.
>
> **Limitations**
>
> DataTemplateSelector instances have the following limitations:
>
> - The DataTemplateSelector subclass must always return the same template
>     for the same data if queried multiple times.
> - The DataTemplateSelector subclass must not return another DataTemplateSelector subclass.
> - The DataTemplateSelector subclass must not return new instances of a
>     DataTemplate on each call. Instead, the same instance must be
>     returned. Failure to do so will create a memory leak and will disable
>     virtualization.
> - On Android, there can be no more than 20 different
>     data templates per ListView.
>
> **Consuming a DataTemplateSelector in XAML**
>
> In XAML, the PersonDataTemplateSelector can be instantiated by
>   declaring it as a resource, as shown in the following code example:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Selector;assembly=Selector" x:Class="Selector.HomePage">
 <ContentPage.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <DataTemplate x:Key="validPersonTemplate">
             <ViewCell>
                ...
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:Key="invalidPersonTemplate">
             <ViewCell>
                ...
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
         <local:PersonDataTemplateSelector x:Key="personDataTemplateSelector"
             ValidTemplate="{StaticResource validPersonTemplate}"
             InvalidTemplate="{StaticResource invalidPersonTemplate}" />
     </ResourceDictionary>
 </ContentPage.Resources>   
    ... 
</ContentPage>
```

> This page level ResourceDictionary defines two DataTemplate instances and a
>   PersonDataTemplateSelector instance. The PersonDataTemplateSelector
>   instance sets its ValidTemplate and InvalidTemplate properties to the
>   appropriate DataTemplate instances by using the StaticResource markup
>   extension. Note that while the resources are defined in the page's
>   ResourceDictionary, they could also be defined at the control level or
>   application level.
>
> The PersonDataTemplateSelector instance is consumed by assigning it to
>   the ListView.ItemTemplate property, as shown in the following code
>   example:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource personDataTemplateSelector}" />
```

> At runtime, the ListView calls the
>   PersonDataTemplateSelector.OnSelectTemplate method for each of the
>   items in the underlying collection, with the call passing the data
>   object as the item parameter. The DataTemplate that is returned by the
>   method is then applied to that object.

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry... I removed the "Executed" column. The problem is that I could have 1 buy and 1 sell, so I need rowspan 2, but I can also have 2 buys and 1 sell, so then I need rowspan 3

Comment: Alright, but whay if I have a List within a List. In the first list for example: Id, trades. And in the second list is the single sell with all the buys that are connected to it. How can I loop through the second list in a grid?

Comment: A list within a list is not recommended, gestures can conflict with each other, and this is true whether developing with Xamarin or native. You may need to create more than one DataTemplate and switch which is used based on what you want to display in any particular list view / collection view cell. You can do this with a DataTemplateSelector. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector